# Set Theory (Example of Set)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A set is defined as the collection of well-defined and distinct objects. Now if we consider the collection of identical glasses, can we call that collection as a set? But I am confused that since all the glasses are exactly of the same color, of the same size, made of the same material and one can't distinguish between any two of them, so isn't that repetition? I need a satisfactory answer, please help me.

Comment: Do the glasses also have the same position in space?

Comment: Obviously they don't have.

Comment: Are you capable of labeling them (with distinct labels) somehow?

Comment: The issue you're worrying about is whether the glasses are individuated by their physical properties. But you needn't have any non-trivial criterion for individuation for them to be, in fact, distinct objects. Incidentally, I loathe the "well-defined, distinct" qualifier I see so often; it seems like it's there to clarify, but it doesn't actually tell you anything useful...

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld, of course I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two objects that have different locations **cannot** be the same object by **definition** of "same". So there are no two **truly identical** glasses. Anyway, please do not assume that set theory applies to glasses. In set theory there are only sets. Glasses, as far as science can see, are not sets. And in fact mathematically we can prove that not everything is a set, for example the collection of all sets...

Comment: Are you sure that the collection of glasses is not a set, I think it is.. The glasses can be assumed to be identical.

Comment: @WaqarAliShah: In set theory, only sets are allowed to be members of a set. Is any glass a set? Not at all. Are you a set? No as well. You **cannot** assume two **different** things are identical. If you disagree, I'll assume that $1 = 0$.

Comment: By "identical" I meant they all are of the same size, same shape, same color and made of the same material.

Comment: If we consider the set {1,2} then 1 and 2 belong to the set but 1 and 2 are not sets. Please explain.

Comment: @WaqarAliShah: In set theory they are. The set of natural numbers is just some set that satisfies certain properties, and there are many such sets.$\def\none{\varnothing}$ A commonly used one is where $0$ is defined as $\none$, and for each natural number $n$, its successor is defined as $n \cup \{n\}$. So $1 = \{\none\}$ and $2 = \{\none,\{\none\}\}$ and so on. This may look stupid, in which case you are not alone. In set theory such a definition produces a very elegant theory of ordinals (counting beyond natural numbers). But set theory cannot talk about real-world objects.

Comment: @WaqarAliShah: It is possible to talk about real-world objects by using a different kind of system, either set theory with urelements (objects that are not sets) or type theory, so I'm just pointing out that you cannot assume that what you are taught in (conventional) set theory **must** apply to the real-world. The reason I say these is because your question involved reasoning about glasses. But set theory has little to do with real-world objects.

Answer (score 0):

A set can't have repetition. For example the set $A$ that contains $1$ would be $\{1\}$ and the set $B$ that contains $1$ and all the elements of $A$ would also be $\{1\}$ not $\{1,1\}$.

Comment: "not $\{1,1\}$"? I would rather say that $\{1\}=\{1,1\}$ since the sets have the same elements (only one wich is $1$) hence are equal. Sets are completely determined by their elements (extensionality). A notation $\{1,1\}$ for set $\{1\}$ is not practical but it is not illegal.

Comment: Yes in a similar way  f x -> x+x then f 1 = 2 and 1+1